# Getting: "rsync: could not open password file" in cygwin

Tags: rsync, cygwin

Running in cygwin

```
rsync -vrtz --password-file=c:\cygwin\secret --delete /cygdrive/d/Data user@xx.xx.xx.xx::modulename
```

But getting

```
rsync: could not open password file c:cygwinsecret: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/authenticate.c(166) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I have tried 'chmod 600 secret' and changing the owner/group in many ways but rsync still cannot seem to see this file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path in cygwin is /cygdrive/c for C:. But you already used it in the same line.
Correct this and try again.